# jQuery Datepick plugin (Keith Wood) julian dates incorrect with daylight savings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am having an issue with Datepick by Keith Wood. I want to display the selected date in julian format in the text box and the calendar pop-up. However, during day-light savings, the calendar pop-up always selects the day before any selection I make. For example, selecting Nov 5th displays the correct date in the calendar pop-up, however, if you select Nov 3rd and then re-open the pop-up, Nov 2nd is displayed as selected in the calendar. This was tested with March 12 as well.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex1018/dzuc19xz/

js

```
$(function () {
  $('#popupDatepicker').datepick({
    dateFormat: 'yyooo',
    onDate: showDayOfYear 
  });
});

function showDayOfYear(date) { 
    return {content: date.getDate() + '<br><sub>' + 
        $.datepick.dayOfYear(date) + '</sub>', dateClass: 'showDoY'}; 
}
```

I have also attached screenshots demonstrating the issue:

309 is selected and 309 is displayed in the calendar.
306 is selected and 305 is displayed in the calendar.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f4Zz.jpg)

Has anyone else experienced this issue? This appears to only be applicable for julian date format.